# How to get only latest data from ngrx/store on reload api call

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am using ngrx/store and ngrx/effects in my angular app.

My issue is that selector in reducer returns old as well as new value after api call from feature state. Below is my code:

reducer.ts

```
case PortfolioActions.PortActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS_TRADE_NAV:
    return {
        ...state,
        navData: action.payload,
        isLoadingNav: false
    };

export const getNavData = createSelector(
    getPortfolioFeatureState,
    state => state.navData
);
```

In effects.ts

```
@Effect()
    loadNav$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
        ofType<fromPortfolio.LoadTradeNAV>(fromPortfolio.PortActionTypes.LOAD_TRADE_NAV),
        switchMap((action) => this.dashSvc.getNetAssetValue(action.payload.key,action.payload.currency)
            .pipe(
                map((data) => {
                    return new fromPortfolio.LoadSuccessTradeNAV(data)
                })
            )
        )
    );
```

In compoenent.ts

```
reload(){
    this.portStore.dispatch(new portfolioActions.LoadTradeNAV(this.searchParam));

    this.portStore.pipe(
    select(fromPortfolio.getNavData),
    filter(f => !!f),
    takeWhile(() => this.componentActive))
    .subscribe((fmtRes) => {
        console.log(fmtRes) //Issue here
        this.data = fmtRes;
    })
}
```

In component when I call `reload()` method, in `subscribe()` I always get the old data and then later on new data after the api call is done.

My question is how can I get the store data only after the api load success is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use withLatestFrom

```
@Effect()
    loadNav$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
        ofType<fromPortfolio.LoadTradeNAV>(fromPortfolio.PortActionTypes.LOAD_TRADE_NAV),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selector))), // pass in your selector here in select()
        switchMap((action) => this.dashSvc.getNetAssetValue(action.payload.key,action.payload.currency)
            .pipe(
                map((data) => {
                    return new fromPortfolio.LoadSuccessTradeNAV(data)
                })
            )
        )
    );
```

Update. I would recommend you put this code in ngOnInit() hook

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.portStore.pipe(
    select(fromPortfolio.getNavData),
    filter(f => !!f),
    takeWhile(() => this.componentActive))
    .subscribe((fmtRes) => {
        console.log(fmtRes) //Issue here
        this.data = fmtRes;
    })
}
```

Comment: Seems we are close. I get previous value on reload not current.